# K means in scikit learn Kernel died - due to long computations

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining, k-means

I am trying to use k means clustering using scikit learn.Hence using the elbow method to find the optimal value of k.

```
def elbow(df, n):
   kMeansVar = [KMeans(n_clusters=k).fit(df.values) for k in range(10, n)]
   centroids = [X.cluster_centers_ for X in kMeansVar]
   k_euclid = [cdist(df.values, cent) for cent in centroids]
   dist = [np.min(ke, axis=1) for ke in k_euclid]
   wcss = [sum(d**2) for d in dist] #TILL HERE THE CODE RAN PROPERLY
   tss = sum(pdist(df.values)**2)/df.values.shape[0]
   bss = tss - wcss
   plt.plot(bss)
   plt.show()
```

My data frame has 14 columns and 188233 rows. When I tried to pass the entire dataframe to the function, the kernel died. When i tried to pass only one single column, even in that case the kernel died. When I tried to triage I was able to figure out the the code ran till the line marked with the comment in the function above. Please suggest me on how to get over this issue.

Comment: what do you mean by died? is your program throwing some error?

Comment: @WasiAhmad No its not showing any error, rather the notebook stops responding and the state of the kernel becomes dead.

Comment: can you check whether is it because of some memory issue? when you are running your program, you can check memory usage. can you do the test with fewer number of rows without changing the number of columns and see what happens?

Comment: @WasiAhmad it worked with 30k rows

Comment: What is the type of `dist[0]` ? When you do `d**2` make sure this is **element-wise** square, some numpy types treat `**2` as **matrix power**, which might be quite expensive for 188k rows :)

Comment: @lejlot type is <class 'numpy.ndarray'>.

Comment: @vikky I believe my guess is correct. you are trying to do memory expensive computation! either you run your code in a system with more memory or you can split the computation in several units.

Comment: @WasiAhmad can u suggest me on how to split the computations. My system has a ram of 16gb

Comment: @vikky execute the operation for certain number of rows every time as a batch and go over the whole matrix in this way.

Comment: Give a try with MiniBatchKMeans. It should work!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than recomputing all the distamces, why don't you use the `inertia_` provided by the k-means object?

Then you won't need your problematic line (which uses inefficient dats structures).